# How to end a while loop which is accepting char continuously

Tags: java

I am checking if an input is a vowel, a consonant or otherwise. I want to breakout of my while loop when any other data type (int, double, long etc.) is entered. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Babatunde
 */
public class vowelConsonantOne {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char ch;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter an Alphabet");
            ch = sc.next().charAt(0);

            if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'a' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'U' || ch == 'u') {
                System.out.println("This is a vowel");
            } else {
                System.out.println("This is a consonant");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: and what is currently happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Character.html) class and its various method: `Character.isLetter` should do the job (`isAlphabetic(int)` works only for code point).

```
        if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'a' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'U' || ch == 'u') {
            System.out.println("This is a vowel");
        } else if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
             System.out.println("This is a consonant");
        } else {
          break; // exit the loop.
        }
```

Or, if you don't want to exit the loop and continue reading characters:

```
     for(;;) {
        System.out.println("Enter an Alphabet");
        char ch = sc.next().charAt(0);
        if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'a' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'U' || ch == 'u') {
            System.out.println("This is a vowel");
        } else if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
             System.out.println("This is a consonant");
        }
      }
```

By the way, you don't need the `Scanner` class:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardDefaultCharsets.UTF_8);
for (;;) {
  System.out.println("Enter an Alphabet");
  int n = isr.read();
  if (n == -1) break; // end of stdin.
  char ch = (char) n;
  // the if here
}
```

Comment: If after i have encountered another data type and break the while loop, how can i let the program continue checking for Alphabets again without having to re-run the program?

Comment: "continue checking for Alphabets" requires staying in the while loop, as currently coded.  If you want to do that, why break out of the loop in the first place?

Comment: FWIW, you mean "an alphabetic character" (or perhaps "a letter"), not "an alphabet".  An alphabet is, for example, ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.

Comment: Fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you add Character.toLowerCase() you only need to check lowercase chars.
To exit a while loop use

```
break;
```

While (true) part:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter an Alphabet");
    ch = Character.toLowerCase(sc.next().charAt(0));

    if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') {
        System.out.println("This is a vowel");
    } else {
        System.out.println("This is a consonant");
        sc.close();
        break;
    }
}
```